# Atmel XMEGA PDI Issue

Tags: avr, xmega

I have an Xmega chip I've been using for a year and had no problems with the PDI interface programming it with the Atmel-ICE debugger/programmer. The problem is I accidentally connected the cable to the "SAM" port instead of the "AVR" Port on the ICE. Now Atmel studio will not program the chip. I keep getting:

PDI enable failed. Debugger command Activate physical failed.
Unable to enter programming mode. Verify device selection, interface settings, target power, security bit, and connections to the target device.

Also, the AVR resets, so I think it is not seeing the PDI clock signal and taking the PDI as a standard reset now...

Why would Atmel make the SAM and AVR ports the same connector?? Could this have really blew out the PDI lines of my chip?

By the way, the chip still works, it is running the old code just fine, I just can't program it now.

Comment: Did you solve this? Maybe a silly question, but after you corrected your mistake, did you power cycle the ICE (unplug the USB cable and plug it back in)?

Comment: I tried that, and also tried another ICE debugger. Now I believe the chip PDI pins are fried, and I am putting a new one in tomorrow :(